# Extracting data from a lxml tree

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

## **Preamble:**

[I followed this guide](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/).

Regretfully, it doesn't work entirely, and as a result I'm unable to extract the data I wish from the lxml tree. I'm not specifically interested in this  specific case; i'm looking for more general answers.

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  
from lxml import html 

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  
  
  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit() 

url = 'http://pycoders.com/archive/'  
#This does the magic.Loads everything
r = Render(url)  
#result is a QString.
result = r.frame.toHtml()
#QString should be converted to string before processed by lxml
formatted_result = str(result.toAscii())

#Next build lxml tree from formatted_result
tree = html.fromstring(formatted_result)
```

The guide continues to do:

```
archive_links = tree.xpath('//divass="campaign"]/a/@href')
```

which results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src\lxml\lxml.etree.pyx", line 1587, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:59353)
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 307, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:171227)
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:170184)
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

## Question

To access my data, I still need to use a correct xpath. For testings sake, I've tried using `title = tree.xpath('//title').`
This leaves me with a `<element title at 0xdf418>` object. I'm unable to extract the data, i.e. the title in this case, from this object.

I've tried a few things, but none actually return the data.

```
>>> title .__len__()
1
>>> title .__sizeof__()
72
>>> type(title)
<type 'list'>
>>>title[0]
<element title at 0xdfc418>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, there is a typo. Try this instead:

```
archive_links = tree.xpath('//div[class="campaign"]/a/@href')
```

Or:

```
archive_links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="campaign"]/a/@href')
```

Comment: That syntax makes more sense, but regretfully it returns `archive_links = [ ] ` for me.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen, This is because you requests initial page source only while to get links you need to wait until `JavaScript` execution completed

Comment: According to the guide, the `Render` class waits for JS to be executed. Am I misunderstanding the guide, is the guide wrong or did you miss the `Render` class?

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen, or maybe I'm wrong in my assumption :) Actually, code line should be `archive_links = tree.xpath(//div[@class="campaign"]/a/@href)`. Note `@class`, not just `class`.